# How do you alter the size of a Pytorch Dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, torch, pytorch

Say I am loading MNIST from `torchvision.datasets.MNIST`, but I only want to load in 10000 images total, how would I slice the data to limit it to only some number of data points?  I understand that the `DataLoader` is a generator yielding data in the size of the specified batch size, but how do you slice datasets?

```
tr = datasets.MNIST('../data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
te = datasets.MNIST('../data', train=False, transform=transform)
train_loader = DataLoader(tr, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, **kwargs)
test_loader = DataLoader(te, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is important to note that when you create the `DataLoader` object, it doesnt immediately load all of your data (its impractical for large datasets). It provides you an iterator that you can use to access each sample.

Unfortunately, `DataLoader` doesnt provide you with any way to control the number of samples you wish to extract. You will have to use the typical ways of slicing iterators.

Simplest thing to do (without any libraries) would be to stop after the required number of samples is reached.

```
nsamples = 10000
for i, image, label in enumerate(train_loader):
    if i > nsamples:
        break

    # Your training code here.
```

Or, you could use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the first 10k samples. Like so.

```
for image, label in itertools.islice(train_loader, stop=10000):

    # your training code here.
```

Comment: A warning for this method: if you iterate the `train_loader` multiple times in a loop over variable `epoch`, you may have already used all the samples for the training... Because the ``shuffle=True`` option in ``DataLoader`` will shuffle the samples for each epoch.

Comment: I keep getting errors like `DataLoader worker (pid(s) 9579) exited unexpectedly` with these methods (on OSX)

Answer (score 29):

You can use `torch.utils.data.Subset()` e.g. for the first 10,000 elements:

```py
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

indices = torch.arange(10000)
tr_10k = data_utils.Subset(tr, indices)
```

Comment: This modifies Dataset not DataLoader and is very clear.

Answer (score 15):

Another quick way of slicing dataset is by using `torch.utils.data.random_split()` (supported in PyTorch v0.4.1+). It helps in randomly splitting a dataset into non-overlapping new datasets of given lengths.

So we can have something like the following:

```
tr = datasets.MNIST('../data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
te = datasets.MNIST('../data', train=False, transform=transform)

part_tr = torch.utils.data.random_split(tr, [tr_split_len, len(tr)-tr_split_len])[0]
part_te = torch.utils.data.random_split(te, [te_split_len, len(te)-te_split_len])[0]

train_loader = DataLoader(part_tr, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, **kwargs)
test_loader = DataLoader(part_te, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, **kwargs)
```

here you can set `tr_split_len` and `te_split_len` as the required split lengths for training and testing datasets respectively.