# Pytorch - Can not slice torchvision MNIST dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, slice

In Pytorch, when using torchvision's MNIST dataset, we can get a digit as follows:

```py
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, TensorDataset

tsfm = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((16, 16)),
                           transforms.ToTensor(),
                           transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])

mnist_ds = datasets.MNIST(root='../../../_data/mnist',train=True,download=True,
                          transform=tsfm)

digit_12 = mnist_ds[12]
```

Though it is possible to slice on many datasets, we cannot slice on this one:

```py
>>> digit_12_to_14 = mnist_ds[12:15]
ValueError: Too many dimensions: 3 > 2.
```

This is due to a `Image.fromarray()` in the `getItem()`.

Is it possible to use MNIST dataset without using a Dataloader?

---

**PS:** The reason why I would like to avoid using Dataloader is that sending batches one at a time to the GPU slows down the training. I prefer to send the entire dataset to the GPU at once. For this I need to have access to the whole *transformed* dataset.

Comment: How about `[mnist_ds[i] for i in range(12,15)]`?

Comment: Thanks. This works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you alter the size of a Pytorch Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856691/how-do-you-alter-the-size-of-a-pytorch-dataset)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `torch.utils.data.Subset()` to get an index based slice of a torch `Dataset` e.g:

```py
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

indices = torch.arange(12,15)
mnist_12to14 = data_utils.Subset(tr, indices)
```

Comment: Great find, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The [`Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) interface only requires that

> All subclasses should override `__len__`, that provides the size of the dataset, and `__getitem__`, supporting integer indexing in range from `0` to `len(self)` exclusive.

which clearly does not mention slicing - the slicing behavior of other datasets is an extra feature. If you want to get the whole data at once, you can look up the [implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torchvision/datasets/mnist.html#MNIST) and just use the `mnist.data` and `mnist.targets` tensors defined towards the end of `__init__`.

If you want to have transformed data, you can use

```
data = [mnist_ds[i] for i in range(len(mnist_ds))]
xs = torch.stack([d[0] for d in data], dim=0)
ys = torch.stack([d[1] for d in data], dim=0)
```

or transform the `mnist.data` tensor all at once (though that will not work with the `torchvision.transform` transforms).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about slicing. mnist.data and mnist.targets are not transformed. One should use __getIem()__ to get transformed images

Comment: My bad, updated. Essentially, use the approach of Fabio Perez

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 solutions so far to convert torchvision MNIST dataset to tensors. The first one is derived from Fábio Perez comment :

```
print("\nFirst...")
st = time()
x_all_ts = torch.tensor([mnist_ds[i][0].numpy() for i in range(0, len(mnist_ds))])
t_all_ts = mnist_ds.train_labels
print(f"{time()-st}   images:{x_all_ts.size()}  targets:{t_all_ts.size()} ")

print("\nSecond...")
st = time()
mnist_dl = DataLoader(dataset=mnist_ds, batch_size=len(mnist_ds))
x_all_ts2, t_all_ts2 = list(mnist_dl)[0]
print(f"{time()-st}   images:{x_all_ts2.size()}  targets:{t_all_ts2.size()} ")


First...
19.573785066604614   images:torch.Size([60000, 1, 16, 16])  targets:torch.Size([60000]) 
Second...
16.826476573944092   images:torch.Size([60000, 1, 16, 16])  targets:torch.Size([60000])
```

Please let me know if you find better ones.